Bug in current WebGL shader implementation concerning variable settings?
We have a framework for doing WegGL shader animations. Since recent version of WebGL we observe strange behaviour.
Everything worked well in Safari up to Mac OS Ventura 13.x and iOS 16.x. Things get messed up for later operation systems like Mac OS Sonoma or iOS 17.x. The problem also arises in Mac OS 16.x under Chrome. Chrome  might use a different WebGL implementation.
I was able to boil down the code to the following piece of code that could be tested on shadertoy:
float last= 1.0;

float test(){
 last=last-.3;
 return last;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ){
 float rr1=test();
 float rr2=test();
 fragColor = vec4(rr1,rr2,0,1);
}

This code should simply produce monochrome screen with an RGBA color value of (.7,.4,0,1.0).

It does so under Older MacOS Versions in Safari.
However, since recently it produces a color (.7,.7,0,1.0).

The value of the variable last gets reset to 1.0, every time the function test() is called.
Am I doing anything wrong? Did the specification of WebGL change?
Does anyone have any ideas on this issue?
(Remark: The issue arises in our own implementation of a Noise generator routine for WebGL)
Remark: The new version of WebGL works correctly if I explicitly set the last variable in the Main routine
(However Our automatic code building environment for our WebGL animations requires things not to be done this way)

